# Highcharts - Unnecessary space issue in pie chart

Tags: jquery, css, charts, highcharts, pie-chart

I am trying to integrate pie chart in my web page. Its working fine but there is extra space in the top and bottom. I don't what those spaces.

[image]

As mentioned in the above image, there is lots of white space in the top and bottom which i don't want. I there any options in the highchart to remove those space? Or can we do using css or anything else?

Below is my sample code which i am working on.

```js
Highcharts.chart('jobs', {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie',
            showLegend: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Parramatta'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Total: 12',
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name} ({point.y}): <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: false,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    x: 0, y: 0,
                    format: '<b>{point.name} ({point.y}):</b><br />{point.percentage:.1f}%'
                },
                showInLegend: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function() {
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Jobs',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [
                {
                name: 'No AFSS',
                y: 4,
                color: '#9933ff',
                },
                {
                name: 'Valid AFSS',
                y: 4,
                color: '#00b04f',
                },
                {
                name: 'Expired AFSS',
                y: 4,
                color: '#ff0000',
                }
            ]
        }]
    });
```

```html
<link href="http://materialwrap-html.authenticgoods.co/assets/css/theme-a.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://materialwrap-html.authenticgoods.co/assets/css/app.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://materialwrap-html.authenticgoods.co/assets/css/vendor.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="jobs"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you create a working snippet producing the issue

Comment: add the below code to your option json array
legend : {
             margin: 5,
              padding: 0
            },

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on the online editor which I could work on?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here I found was with your `col-xs-4` class, removing it brings the chart to full size. Can you check is this class necessary, the updated chart with the class removed is added to the snippet.

> Also pie chart has data labels, container will take the space to show data labels also. Removing data labels and adding size 100% will show the chart in full size

```js
function renderChart(id) {
  Highcharts.chart(id, {
    chart: {
      plotBackgroundColor: null,
      plotBorderWidth: null,
      plotShadow: false,
      type: 'pie',
      showLegend: false,
      spacingTop: 0,
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Parramatta'
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Total: 12',
    },
    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: '{series.name} ({point.y}): <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    exporting: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        allowPointSelect: false,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        size: '100%',
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          inside:true,
          distance:-55,
          format: '<b>{point.name} ({point.y}):</b><br />{point.percentage:.1f}%'
        },
        showInLegend: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
          events: {
            click: function() {

            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Jobs',
      colorByPoint: true,
      data: [{
          name: 'No AFSS',
          y: 4,
          color: '#9933ff',
        },
        {
          name: 'Valid AFSS',
          y: 4,
          color: '#00b04f',
        },
        {
          name: 'Expired AFSS',
          y: 4,
          color: '#ff0000',
        }
      ]
    }]
  });
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    renderChart(`jobs${i}`)
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="http://materialwrap-html.authenticgoods.co/assets/css/theme-a.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://materialwrap-html.authenticgoods.co/assets/css/app.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://materialwrap-html.authenticgoods.co/assets/css/vendor.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="jobs0"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="jobs1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="jobs2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="jobs3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i have added because i need 4 columns in desktop so i am getting this issue in desktop. In the snippet if we remove xs-4, its showing in full screen so there is no issue.
Please try it in full screen output

Comment: can you share your wireframe, how many charts do you need to show in full size ??

Comment: the only workaround I found is to set the size to 100% and remove the data labels, then the chart will be in full size. I will update the snippet.

Comment: when i set dataLabels.enabled=true, its not showing labels

Comment: Please go through the added solution

Comment: @AmarshiJamod yes we can, check the updated snippet, and if it helped to solve your issue, please accept the answer and give and upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the responsive feature to change the chart size for a smaller chart width.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rhygLqok/

```
  responsive: {
    rules: [{
      condition: {
        maxWidth: 300
      },
      // Make the labels less space demanding on mobile
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          height: 300
        }
      }
    }, {
      condition: {
        minWidth: 300
      },
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          height: 400
        }
      }
    }]
  }
```

Width > 300 -> sets chart height back to 400 (which is set by default)

Width < 300 -> sets chart height to 300 (there is no space)

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/responsive